# Android - jdbc won't connect

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

My JDBC driver is unable to establish a connection to my database. Could someone please check to see whether my connection string is incorrect or if something else is wrong?

My conn string is as follows: `"jdbc:sqlserver://IPADDR\\INSTANCE;databaseName=DBNAME";`

My code is as follows:

```java
private Connection connection = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        try {
            Class.forName(Classes);
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username,password);
            textView.setText("SUCCESS");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            textView.setText("ERROR");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            textView.setText("FAILURE");
        }
    }

    public void sqlButton(View view){
        if (connection!=null){
            Statement statement = null;
            try {
                statement = connection.createStatement();
                ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("Select * from table;");
                while (resultSet.next()){
                    textView.setText(resultSet.getString(1));
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else {
            textView.setText("Connection is null");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @peet214 - are you getting any errors (if so what?)? have you confiqured a SQLServer JDBC driver?

Comment: I am not getting any errors.

Comment: Hi @peet214 - so what makes you think the connection isn't happening?

Comment: @MrR I honestly don't really have a clue, this is my first time working with jdbc and java all together. I personally think it has to do with the connection string.

Comment: Aside... are you sure you want Android apps on mobile devices accessing your SQL Server? The TDS (Tabular Data Stream) protocol is designed for use on local area networks and because it's so "chatty" and has many round-trip operations it suffers badly in high-latency environments such as WAN/cellular networks. Mobile applications normally talk to some kind of web APIs, like RESTful web services, that are located much closer to the SQL Server/s and hide all of the database logic and queries behind themselves.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning it's an app for personal use so no worrying about that.